# require.js - unable to load any further modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs

**Hello everyone.**

this is how I'm loading **jquery** and **jquery.validate** extension.. Everything is okay untill  I try to add any other modules.. .

```
define( ['jquery', 'jquery_validate'], function($){
  dostuff()
});
```

.
Tried this but now it thinks that **domReady** is **jquery.validate** ..

```
define( ['jquery', 'jquery_validate', 'domReady'], function($, domReady){
     domReady(function (){
       dostuff()
     });
});
```

I guess it might work like this...any ideas?

```
 define( ['jquery', 'jquery_validate'], function($, require){
    var domR = require(['domReady']);
    dostuff()
});
```

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
define( ['jquery', 'domReady', 'jquery_validate'], function($, domReady){
```

RequireJS will call your factory function (the callback you give to `define`) with arguments that are in the same number and order as the dependencies you give to `define` (or to `require`). If a module returns an undefined value, then the corresponding value will be `undefined` **but it is still there**.

Since the order of the dependencies in a `define` call is meaningless from the standpoint of telling RequireJS what to do, the traditional way to handle modules that return `undefined` values or values we don't care about is to put them *at the end* of the dependency list and omit their arguments, like I did above for `jquery_validate`.